# Caesar for CS50x wrap around breaks for certain characters in C

Tags: c, cs50

Currently in my 2nd week of coding and a problem is unusal.
As per the below code, everything works fine but wrap around for lowercase letters after "t" doesn't work on certain keys, I even had to make a second char `b`, thinking that maybe it's something else. but no luck.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        char a = text[i] + key;
        char b = text[i] + key;
        if (isupper(text[i]))
        {
            while (a > 90)
            {
                a = a - 26;
            }
            printf("%c", a);
        }

        else if (islower(text[i]))
        {
            while ( b > 122)
            {
                b = b - 26;
            }
            printf("%c", b);
        }
        else
        {
            char c = text[i];
            printf("%c", c);
        }
```

Output on Upper case letters is fine.
Output for some lower case letters is also fine.
I'm scratching my head as to what is going on here

Comment: Your `char` is likely signed, so you are probably overflowing it somewhere. Perform the calculations on `int`s instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks! that is exactly what the problem was. That was very fast thanks!

Comment: Use `'Z'` instead of `90` and `'z'` instead of `122` to make your code readable. (no *MagicNumbers*) You can also `#define ABETSZ 26` and take care of the rest of your *MagicNumbers*...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the input. those magic number also did not sit well with me. I will change to reflect the same.

Comment: And to tidy up, remove `strlen(text);` from your `for` loop declaration and use `for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++)` as the loop. Eliminates the function call and simply uses the nul-character at the end of the string (e.g. `0`) as the loop terminating condition. You also don't want an unoptimized `strlen(text)` called every iteration to check for the loop exit condition `:)`  But you took the right approach -- get it working -- then worry about any optimization tweaks.